javax.smartcardio cannot be resolved after updating Maven project to Java 17
I recently updated my Maven project from Java 8 to Java 17. After the update, I encountered an issue where Eclipse cannot resolve javax.smartcardio.* imports in my project. I found a workaround by adding java.smartcardio as a system module through Eclipse's project settings (Configure Build Path -> Module Dependencies -> add System Module -> java.smartcardio).
However, every time I update my Maven project (Right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project), the java.smartcardio module gets removed, and I have to add it again manually.
I found a similiar post, however all provided solutions still encounter the issue where java.smartcardio module gets removed when maven project is updated.
Reference link: How to add module 'java.smartcardio' in a non-modular JavaFX application?
Is there a permanent solution to this issue?
I tried adding java.smartcardio module as a system module manually to the Eclipse .classpath file of my project:
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-17">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="limit-modules" value="java.se,jdk.accessibility,jdk.dynalink,jdk.httpserver,jdk.incubator.foreign,jdk.incubator.vector,jdk.jartool,jdk.javadoc,jdk.jconsole,jdk.jshell,jdk.jsobject,jdk.management.jfr,jdk.net,jdk.nio.mapmode,jdk.sctp,jdk.security.auth,jdk.security.jgss,jdk.unsupported,jdk.unsupported.desktop,jdk.xml.dom,java.smartcardio"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>

However, this did not solve the issue when updating maven project where the smartcardio module was removed.

This feels like either 1) you're supposed to configure the module in Maven somewhere, and Eclipse is updating its module list to match the (empty) list in Maven; 2) this is a bug in Eclipse.

The question you've linked's answer does have a checkbox 'Update project config from pom.xml' to untick. That sounds like exactly what's happening here. Did you untick that? However if that fixes it then I think it's a bug that you'd need to do that.

And you've got <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/> in your snippet, which sounds like exactly what you don't want, as it sounds like the problem is that this isn't in your POM.

@Rup Yes, I did untick the checkbox for 'Update project config from pom.xml' and it works. However, this approach can lead to issues because it prevents Maven from recognizing newly added dependencies or updated ones. Additionally, changes in build settings and updates to Maven plugins specified in pom.xml may not be applied correctly. This defeats the purpose of updating the Maven project effectively.
I totally agree with you that the problem is a bug in Eclipse's integration with Maven.

A project without a module-info.java is a non-modular project. When you need dependencies as modules (e.g. because of services declared in the module declarations), you need to add a module-info.java file: right-click the project and choose Configure > Create module-info.java. A project that is partly non-modular and partly modular makes no sense and, as far as I know, is not covered by the Java language specification.

@howlger I added a module-info.java file in src/main/java for my Spring Boot project. Now, test classes in src/test/java show import errors like: "The package org.bouncycastle.util.encoders is accessible from more than one module: , org.bouncycastle.provider.". If I remove requires org.bouncycastle.provider, the test errors disappear, but then classes in src/main/java get errors like: "The type org.bouncycastle.pqc.math.linearalgebra.ByteUtils is not accessible."
Do you know why this is happening? Am I missing something?

It seems that a JAR of a test dependency contains the package org.bouncycastle.util.encoders which is already included in the org.bouncycastle.provider module (everything on the classpath is considered in the <unnamed> module and two modules must not contain the same package). Does removing of that test dependency work?

@howlger Thank you for your suggestion, it worked perfectly! I still need to review my code to address some issues related to how I've managed the code and modules. Thanks again for your help!
